# Access Multiple records from a single form input, with some fields differing

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a form in which customers can submit testing with me. There are multiple test methods they can choose from, and they may want multiple methods on the same sample.

This in and of itself isn't the issue, the issue arises from the fact that they may want different amount of test runs per method, but all on the same sample. E.g. Sample 1 comes in for Method A (2runs), Method B (1run)--> As can be seen by PersonB with sample2 in the screenshot below.

How can i set up the input form to prompt them for a runs value (and sample value-See screenshot) when they select the method, but also have it so the table displays/holds the information in a single record per method, as shown in the table below?

At the moment they need to add a single method at a time for it to achieve what i have so far.

Note: The methods dropdown box on the form is bound to a different table that only contains the methods so we can allow them to only pick methods we either have available or are in service at that time.

[image: SubForm]

^The submit button saves the data to the table and clears the form to display what is seen above, the Delete button just clears the form. LabBatchID is also an autonumber, that's just handy for us to be aware of.

[image: SubTable]

Any help would be great and much appreciated, if you have any specific questions please let me know.

Kind regards,
Ben

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question correctly. But it seems you can use two tables as master-detail with the [IRIS Batch ID] , [Requester] as the fields of master table, and [IRIS Batch ID] , [Samples] ,[Runs],[Method] as the fields of detail table linked with [IRIS Batch ID].  Then put the detail form as a sub-form in the submission form. You can later denormalize the results if it is really the desired output.

Comment: @ShahramAlemzadeh, I'm not entirely sure what you mean if im honest. I'm still fairly new to using Access at an author/creator level.

Can i ask what you aren't quiet sure/understanding about within the question?

Comment: I mean I am not sure if the master-detail forms, is really what you need. Is the data structure being like: orders/order details, students/classes ... ? or something else is in your mind.

Comment: Hi Shahram, If you are referring to where the data from the form goes then its the Sample Submission table structure as shown in the 2nd image. This table is then what everything else generally with refer to, the only exceptions that jump to mind is that the Requester and Method drop-down boxes in the form are linked to their own tables-I.e. the selection is made from their specific table, but once submitted they populate the Sample Submission table. I have attempted to upload additional images and explanation but the image wont upload for some reason.

Comment: Question is too broad, lacks code for analysis, responses would be nature of opinion and is therefore not appropriate for SO. Might want to post in a discussion type form where you could even attach your db for analysis.